# Решение кроссбраузерности единиц vh и vw в gulp-sass

Tags: gulp, sass, gulp-sass

Всем доброго времени суток.Единицы `vh` и `vw`(как и некоторые другие) понимают не все браузеры(особенно мобильные).Кто знает решение данного вопроса через `gulp-sass`?И еще, если в gulp установить `autoprefixer`, то как настроить, чтобы он ставил префиксы не только `-webkit, -moz и -o`, но и `-ms`?В `gulpfile.js` стоит `browsers: ['last 15 versions']`, но `-ms` не ставится.